# identifying release files in Bower packages

Tags: javascript, bower

Having just started to use Bower to manage front-end dependencies, I'm rather confused by the apparent lack of packaging conventions:

After installing a package, I usually end up with what looks like an unfiltered Git repository - with no cue which files constitute the actual release. For example, `bower install requirejs` generates a bunch of files in `./bower_components/requirejs/dist/` - but as far as I can tell (I'm just guessing based on exploring the package directory), the file to use is `./bower_components/requirejs/require.js`. Other packages place their release files in different locations.

Am I missing something, an implicit convention perhaps, or is this lack of consistency currently the state of the art, likely due to Bower still being relatively young?

(Please note that I'm not trying to criticize Bower here, merely trying to understand what I couldn't seem to google.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are. The main file is indicated in the `bower.json` file as the  `"main"` entry. The format is intentionally "we don't care how you order your files and directories, as long as you indicate all the bower-relevant things in bower.json", which means that you will indeed get entire git directories for things that are "also a bower package" or even just have a single file out of the entire repo that is bower-registered.

For the bower.json spec (which is actually really small) see http://bower.io/#defining-a-package

Comment: Thanks, I'd looked at Bower's documentation, but that didn't clearly answer the question for me.